# "Idiomatic" block-quote formatting in a two-column paper?

Tags: two-column, acmart, quotation

I'd like to use a short(ish) quote, of a paragraph, within my article. However, if I use an environment such as `{quote}`, there's a *massive* indentation - something like 25% of the entire column text width is taken up by the indent, making it feel rather awkward, and take up a lot of space.

I was wondering how people idiomatically format or lay out such block quotes in the more narrow format of two-column (A4 or letter) text.

I was thinking of elements such as a background hatch, italicizing the font or changing its family; using a frame; using a bar on one or both sides; using some graphical element at the beginning and ending corner (top-left and bottom-right for LTR languages); or some combination of the above. But - I don't want something innovative or novel, and certainly not something which would attract too much attention or seem garish.

Notes:

- Assume the document class itself does not include any specific settings for quoted text (e.g. because they're rare and the class authors didn't bother with that).
- While its true I could just decrease the margins, that would make the quote difficult to distinguish from the rest of the text.

<sub>If the question seems too general: I'm using the [`acmart.cls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acmart) document class - the ACM's master document class - with the `sigconf` option (here's a [sample document](https://www.cse.wustl.edu/~lu/CPSWeek2017-Typesetting/ACM%20Template/sample-sigconf.pdf)); so, you can answer assuming that's how the document looks like in general.</sub>

Comment: The `quoting`  package  enables you to control many parameters of  the eponymous environment, among which its left and right margins.f

Comment: Quote and quotation are set by the document class and are usually lists, using the same \leftmargin as itemize etc.  If you do not intend to nest quotes with other lists, you can simply set \leftskip and \rightskip within your own environment.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Often, they're _not_ set by the document class; but see my edit.

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, I've already "adopted" quoting. But - what should I actually have it do? Smaller margins only avoids one aspect of the problem, I still need to do something instead of having deep marings.

Comment: You can choose the font too. As to adding some frame or left bar, you can try with the `frarmed` package, or the more sophisticated `tcolorbox`.

Comment: @Bernard: I know I _can_ do those things. The question is what _should_ I do...

Comment: Personally, I would set s smaller font size and add some small vertical padding.

Answer (score 2):

What I've done as a sort of an easy default is use the [`quoting`](https://ctan.org/pkg/quoting) package, like so:

```
\usepackage[vskip=1em,font=itshape,leftmargin=2em,rightmargin=2em]{quoting}
```

[image]

I would have reduced the margins even further, but then the left side of the quote seems sort of flush with the nexr paragraph's indent.